# how to select non match

Tags: sql

I have four columns of contact namely `contact1`, `contact2`, `contact3`, `contact4`.
How to write sql to get unique contacts from 4 contacts?

```
contact1   contact2   contact3   contact4
8888498756 8888498756 8888498756 8888498756
```

These are four same contacts how to get unique only in sql.

```
select ca.propno, ca.contact1, ca.contact2, ca.mobile1, ca.mobile2
from BIUSR.tbl_trn_customer_address ca
where ca.contact1 not in (ca.contact2, ca.mobile1, ca.mobile2)
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Also provide sample data and desired results.  It is unclear what you want to do and what your query has to do with your question.

Comment: Please specify what unique means more adequately. Do you want to get  a null? What is the end result you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The DISTINCT and UNION might give you what you need.

```
SELECT DISTINCT propno, contact
FROM (

select ca.propno, ca.contact1 contact 
 from BIUSR.tbl_trn_customer_address ca
UNION
select ca.propno, ca.contact2 contact 
 from BIUSR.tbl_trn_customer_address ca
UNION
select ca.propno, ca.mobile1 contact 
 from BIUSR.tbl_trn_customer_address ca
UNION
select ca.propno, ca.mobile2 contact 
 from BIUSR.tbl_trn_customer_address ca) contacts
```

Comment: This query will not list all the unique number in 1 row as required here.

Comment: The alias 'contacts' on the table can be removed.  It is valid on sql_server but not on others

Answer (score 0):

If I got it right

```
select ca.propno, ca.contact1
     , case when ca.contact1 != ca.contact2 then ca.contact2 end contact2
     , case when ca.mobile1 not in (ca.contact1, ca.contact2) then ca.mobile1 end contact3
     , case when ca.mobile2 not in (ca.contact1, ca.contact2, ca.mobile1) then ca.mobile2 end contact4
from BIUSR.tbl_trn_customer_address ca
```

Comment: there are missing values in contact1, contact2, mobile1 and mobile2. How to tackle them

Comment: For prop no A1 there are 3 distinct contact but I am getting only one distinct how?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to add `primary key` to the table

Here is the solution tested with all scenarios

```
CREATE TABLE tblData1 (
    id int PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL IDENTITY(1, 1),
    contact1 nvarchar(25) NOT NULL,
    contact2 nvarchar(25) NOT NULL,
    contact3 nvarchar(25) NOT NULL,
    contact4 nvarchar(25) NOT NULL,

 );

  INSERT INTO tblData1 (contact1, contact2, contact3, contact4) VALUES ('8888498756', '8888498756', '8888498756', '8888498756');
  INSERT INTO tblData1 (contact1, contact2, contact3, contact4) VALUES ('8888498751', '8888498756', '8888498756', '8888498756');
  INSERT INTO tblData1 (contact1, contact2, contact3, contact4) VALUES ('8888498756', '8888498751', '8888498756', '8888498756');
  INSERT INTO tblData1 (contact1, contact2, contact3, contact4) VALUES ('8888498756', '8888498756', '8888498751', '8888498756');
  INSERT INTO tblData1 (contact1, contact2, contact3, contact4) VALUES ('8888498756', '8888498756', '8888498756', '8888498751');
  INSERT INTO tblData1 (contact1, contact2, contact3, contact4) VALUES ('8888498756', '8888498756', '8888498752', '8888498752');
  INSERT INTO tblData1 (contact1, contact2, contact3, contact4) VALUES ('8888498756', '8888498752', '8888498756', '8888498752');
  INSERT INTO tblData1 (contact1, contact2, contact3, contact4) VALUES ('8888498752', '8888498756', '8888498756', '8888498752');

  WITH CTE1 AS
  (
    SELECT id, contact1, contact2, contact3, contact4 FROM tblData1
    )


    SELECT
    CASE WHEN (a.contact1 <> CTE1.contact2) AND (a.contact1 <> CTE1.contact3) AND (a.contact1 <> CTE1.contact4) THEN a.contact1
    ELSE
        CASE WHEN (a.contact2 <> CTE1.contact1) AND (a.contact2 <> CTE1.contact3) AND (a.contact2 <> CTE1.contact4) THEN a.contact2
        ELSE
            CASE WHEN (a.contact3 <> CTE1.contact1) AND (a.contact3 <> CTE1.contact2) AND (a.contact3 <> CTE1.contact4) THEN a.contact3
            ELSE 
                CASE WHEN (a.contact4 <> CTE1.contact1) AND (a.contact4 <> CTE1.contact2) AND (a.contact4 <> CTE1.contact3) THEN a.contact4
                ELSE ''
                END
            END
        END
    END
    FROM tblData1 a
    LEFT JOIN CTE1 ON a.id = CTE1.id
```

Here is the result:

[image]